# Can you restrict Chatter mentions by Profile in Salesforce Communities?

Tags: community, chatter

We have 1 Community that both internal and external users of the company have access to. We've created 2 separate Salesforce Profiles for each:

```
Internal Community User
External Community User
```

Currently, our External users can `@mention` internal users when posting a question to the Community forum (Chatter).

Is there a way to turn off/restrict the external user's ability to `@mention` people?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best,

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

> You can do one thing. Write trigger on feeditem and get body of
>   message then you can check if string contains you group name and
>   profile is not matched. Then add error message. using
>   trigger.New[0].addError();

[**Source link**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com//questions/103750/disabling-mention-of-a-public-group-by-certain-profiles-only-in-chatter-salesfo.html)

Also check this out may be this will help [**User and Group @Mentions—Visibility**](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_mention_visibility.htm&language=en_US)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this as follow:

- Create a trigger on FeedItem
- Create a map of Id and user of outside users
- Now loop on All new feedItems and do something like following trigger code:

  trigger ChatterFeedItemTriggerAI on FeedItem (after insert) {

  ```
  List<Incident__c> toUpdate = new List<Incident__c>();

  Set<Id> usersIdSet= New Set<Id>();

  //Collect all ParentIds    
  for(FeedItem record : trigger.New){
      usersIdSet.add(record.Id);
  }

  Map<Id,User> outSideUserMap = New Map<id,User>([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN:usersIdSet AND Profile.Name = 'outside User']);

  for(FeedItem record : trigger.New){
      ConnectApi.FeedElement feedItem = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement(record.NetworkScope, record.Id);
     List<ConnectApi.MessageSegment> messageSegments = feedItem.body.messageSegments;
     for (ConnectApi.MessageSegment messageSegment : messageSegments) {
          if (messageSegment instanceof ConnectApi.MentionSegment && outSideUserMap.containsKey(record.InsertedById)) {
              record.addError('You are not authorized to add mention!');
              Break;
          }

      }
  }
  ```

  }

This is not tested code, so Please try and change if anything wrong.

Let me know if you have any doubt about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to remove the option for external community members from mentioning (or viewing after typing '@' symbol) other fellow members in Salesforce Communities:

1.) In Setup ---> Sharing Settings, Set the Default External Access "Users" to private.

2.) In Setup ---> Sharing Settings, Uncheck both "Portal User Visibility" and "Community User Visibility" checkboxes.

[image: Salesforce Communities restrict mentions members visibility mentioning]

Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_user_sharing.htm&type=5